# Criando uma coluna dummy baseada no valor de outras colunas

Tags: postgresql

Tenho uma tabela com 200 colunas. Essa tabela possui colunas que identificam o indivíduo (id) e ano (ano).

Preciso verificar se o id enviou informações naquele ano. Se 0, não enviou. Se 1, enviou.

Para isso, preciso verificar se os valores das colunas (c10001, c10002,...,c69993) são todos iguais a 0, para determinado indivíduo e ano.

Exemplo de como eu quero que a tabela fique:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- c10001, c10002,c69993 são as colunas que já possuo e quero verificar os valores.

A princípio pensei em criar um *loop* verificando coluna por coluna até encontrar alguma com valor. Mas acredito ter forma mais eficiente de fazer isso.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Comment: Qual o sentido de você ter múltiplas `Dummy_aaaa` se, pelo que entendi, apenas a coluna referente ao mesmo valor da coluna `ano` poderá ser 1 e as demais necessariamente 0? Será que a função `crosstab`de `tablefunc` não poderia ser uma alternativa? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html

Comment: Tentou criar uma "coluna virtual" ? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html seria algo como (c10001=0 and c10002=0 ...)

Comment: @Motta pelo o que entendi, isso serve para modificar e utilizar os valores das colunas sem alterar a tabela original. É isso? Ele exibe a tabela que eu quero, mas não a salva no banco? Se for, ajudara muito, embora eu tenha certeza que meu chefe irá pedir para adicionar as colunas no banco.

Comment: @anonimo eu acho que isso pode ser uma alternativa sim! estou vendo exemplos e pensando em como usar no meu caso. Ainda estou meio confuso.Obrigado!

Comment: @Rxt Colunas virtuais são aquelas que sendo fruto de um cálculo seriam redundantes serem criadas fisicamente , exemplo valor , valor_pago e 'saldo' , esta poderia ser calculada , no seu caso a calculada poderia refletir a regra complicada das 200 colunas , não sei o desempenho disto e nem o quanto seria usada , difícil opinar sem maiores detalhes.